# Overloaded wire/outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

My wife was trying to “multi task” and now I’m freaking out that we maybe damaged some wires in walls ( I’m paranoid )

She had connected hair dryer and clothe steamer to bedroom outlet

Outlet 15 AMP @ 120V ( 2nd floor bedroom so decent run of copper )

14/2 Wire (Romex)

Hair Dryer 1875W

Steamer 1300W
TV 200W?

So circuit was loaded **30AMP** ( and rated for Max 15AMP)

All this was connected for maybe **2 minutes** and I noticed …

**Breaker didn’t trip** for some reason it’s newish Siemens CAFCI so don’t think that it’s faulty?

I used KillAWatt and the devices do use the wattage that they are listed for.

I did remove outlet to inspect visually the wire and it does not appear to be burnt ( maybe just half way in box a bit darker but could be in my head no discoloration at first inch from outlet screw )

So question is did I maybe melt wire in wall and why breaker didn’t trip.

Sorry for long question

Comment: Was everything turned on and operating at max load?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, it was turned on for 2 minutes maybe less

Comment: A [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256962/overloaded-wire-outlet#comment517102_256967) was made on an answer, but I think it's worth repeating here. Heating devices (heater, toaster, steamer, etc.) do _not_ run at full capacity all the time. They heat a bit above the set temp, then the element turns off and the device is allowed to cool a bit below the set temp, then turns on again. Just like your home heating. It's very possible that there was never much more than 15A being drawn at any one time because of the cycling of the heating elements in the 2 devices.

Comment: This means that it's entirely possible that there was never anything at all for you to worry about and your paranoia is nothing more than that - paranoia. It _is_ possible, of course, that they were both on and drawing full power at the same time, but as the (current) answers have stated, this is well within the safety limits of all the devices and wiring in your house.

Comment: Thank you, I got smart meter, so I can confirm that they were both on, see clear +30AMP spike on top of normal load ( and wife said that she turned one after another )

Comment: Code requires that a dedicated 20 amp circuit be provided to the bathroom, so why not use the hair dryer in the bathroom as code intended?

Comment: Hi Glen, oh yes she will :)

Comment: Just a quick update, I think I checked all connections and all looks ok ? There was a black spot on neutral wire ( I think comming from downstairs feed ? ) but it just scraped off, maybe it was just dirt/scratch marks. But all connections appeared not melted, sadly two outlets were back stabbed down the circuit, but those outlets were recently replaced by electrican as they were yellowed from sun ( so backstab was hopefully good ) - no signs of overheating at those outlets, i took quick glance at lights without removing much and nothing obvious

Comment: You can find on YouTube some experiments of technicians deliberately overloading wires to see what happens. Seems like it takes a massive overload and/or some significant time for the wire to overheat. You can see e.g. they will put 3 times the normal current through a wire, come back in 15 minutes and the wire is very hot but still okay. (Then they up the current to 4-5 times and the wire eventually melts, or they get bored and raise it to 20 times and the wire melts instantly) So that's reassuring.

Comment: @NotSoHandy, the connections are where hotspots usually form.  If you didn't see any melted or charred spots, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 18):

Here's the thing: circuit breakers are not designed to trip instantly as soon as current exceeds the rated limit. Instant trips happen only when the current flow is many times the rated amperage (i.e. a short circuit). This is called a **magnetic** trip.

Otherwise, for excess current up to low tens of the rated current, the trip is delayed, somewhat in proportion to the multiplier. This is called a **thermal** trip and is specified by a **trip curve** chart. This is matched to the expected heating of the protected wires and prevents nuisance trips.

With a typical residential CB, for 2X the rated current flow, the trip time is measured in minutes! It is perfectly acceptable for a 15 amp CB to carry 30 amps for more than two minutes, because it will take more time for the wires to get hot enough to pose a hazard.

My expectation is that if you had waited 5 or 10 minutes, the CB would have tripped.

Comment: Thank you, I was ready to have electrican rip all wires and re wire, this put my mind at ease, I guess I can sleep at night and carry on with circuit use as normal just light loads

Comment: Agree with all of DoxyLover's explanation BUT, your load--using your numbers-- gives 28.125A, which exceeds the ampacity of 14awg copper. It is unlikely the wire was damaged, but you need to upgrade to 12awg copper or ensure you never load it more than 15-20A in the future. I hate 14awg in almost every possible residential circuit for this reason.

Comment: @peinal Would that also not factor in to this answer in the same way?  Ampacity is a max value for continuous current flow, and also has to do with the wire heating.  Wouldn't the trip curve on the CB be such that it trips before the wire overheats too much?  Like my understanding is that the reason the breaker doesnt trip right away is because a 15A circuit  can handle that 30A without issue for a short time.

Comment: Exactly. Breakers are expected to trip before the rated wire insulation temperature is exceeded. So if you heat up a breaker "slowly" the wires would also have heated up slowly. And the breaker would still trip before the wire becomes an issue. If everything was installed and working correctly then there is no issue.

Comment: JMac--not necessarily. If the CB were too large, the wire could melt before tripping. They are related, but both must be correctly sized for the load.

Comment: @peinal I still dont understand your original comment really.  They dont need to upgrade the wire or take any special steps to ensure they dont overload the circuit as far as I understand.  The whole point of the codes and equipment ratings is so that if they overloaded the circuit, it would trip before damage is done, because the wire size and breaker size match.  Everything is being used as intended, besides putting too much load on the circuit, and the breakers are there to make that unintended use a non-issue.

Answer (score 7):

I found one Siemens trip curve at [this link for PDF](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:046fbb46-cb38-482b-9d02-21b7eab7cb54/sie-tc-qp-bq-bl-qt-15-70a-1p.pdf). It shows roughly 17 seconds to 75 seconds (yes, that big a range) for a 2X trip. 2 minutes is longer than 75 seconds (1.25 minutes), but not that much longer and your usage may have varied within that time. I would expect that within another 30 seconds or so you would have had a trip.

A couple of other notes for future readers of this question:

- CAFCI, AFCI, GFCI, etc. have *nothing* to do with this. If you have *faulty* wiring then under load an arcing problem will get worse, triggering AFCI trip, and a loose connection might overload causing a break of sorts which could trigger a GFCI. But basically if the wiring is in good shape then the only thing that will stop an overload situation is the basic breaker functionality, which is independent of the other stuff.
- With modern good quality breakers (Siemens, Eaton, GE, etc.), even if several years old, there is every expectation that an overcurrent trip will happen in a reasonable amount of time. However, there are certain older types - e.g., Federal Pacific, Challenger - where they may **not** trip, or may fail closed rather than open. Those can and do catch fire. So if anyone reading this has one of those breakers (or any other breaker not already listed, as there are other good breakers and other bad breakers) search to find out what may be going on.

Comment: Thank you!, Based on this information, all should be ok and I can sleep well ?, should I cut open drywall and check wires

Comment: No! The only thing I would check is junction boxes. That's where wires get damaged, loose connections, etc. Even that is more than most people would do, but that at least has some logic to it - i.e., if something was marginal (e.g., a back-stab connection or loose wire nut) then an overload is likely to make things worse. But the actual wire runs? Unless there is a particularly unusual situation, the wire runs should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, so by junction boxes you mean, every outlet and light on the circuit ? ( checking for burnt wire at the screws ), light switches ( I have some smart switches )

Comment: I would not be so worried myself. My point though if you are really worried is that the places to check would be any box where the full power would have passed through. Which would probably *not* include every light or switch but would include every receptacle, but hard to know without a full map of your circuit.

Comment: Thank you, I know that this breaker has 2 lights and couple of outlets … not sure if breakers would normally travel via light switches or how I can identify that

Comment: The power used by an unswitched receptacle will not travel through a switch on the same circuit. However, it is possible that the hot and neutral wires for a receptacle might have a connection in a box that *also* has a light switch. There are too many possible legal wiring schemes to guess. But what you should *not* do is actually break/redo any connections *unless* there are indications of problems. In other words, if you are concerned enough to do so, take off each cover plate, check for any: burnt or melted insulation or wire nuts, feel for any loose connections, check for any back stab

Comment: connections (wire directly into back of receptacle instead of into a screw/clamp or wrapped around a screw - back stabs are worth redoing as screw connections), etc. and then put the cover back on. Only do any real work if you find indications of problems. Otherwise you run the risk that you might take off a good connection and put it back together as a *not as good* connection. Really.

Comment: Thank you, will do, I’m sure some were backstabbed as this was cookie cutter builder that build 200 of same homes. ( but hopefully the backstabs didn’t get chance to go bad )

Comment: Hopefully the push in connectors were okay for those 2 minutes because I know that light fixtures used them :(

Comment: The light fixtures are not the issue - they will only have the current they actually use. But receptacles *can* act as a bridge, and then the full current flows through the wires/connections. They are not always done that way - they can also be wired using pigtails and then only the wire nut connection "sees" the full current flow.

Comment: Understood, thank you

Comment: Hairdryers don't necessarily run full power all the time anyway. Depending on how many positions the switch has they can run e.g. hot (max rated power), less hot (reduced power), or cold (very little power).  And a steamer will have a thermostat so once the water is boiling the element will turn on and off - if that was plugged in a few minutes before the hairdryer it won't have been drawing full current all the time.  That could easily explain it not tripping in 2 minutes when the spec is 75s.

Answer (score 3):

I may get snipped for this, but frankly, most electrical has some level of safety margin built into it.  Normally a couple of minutes of over-use won't hurt anything. The wires in the wall won't melt except under **EXTREME** overloads, connections are much more likely to fail first.

Since the breaker didn't trip, it probably wasn't too much of an over use. The wires / connections might have gotten warm, but since connections are required to  be in boxes, you're pretty safe.  Still, you did due diligence in checking the outlets.

If the real load was as high as you think it is, I am worried that the breaker didn't trip with that amount of load...something to look into.

Comment: Hi George, not sure if important I think this outlet is almost at the end of circuit. The breaker is literally 3 weeks old installed by electrican, old breaker was AFCI and new CAFCI, should I check downstream outlets or if the overloaded outlet connections don’t appear to be melted there is no need ), I’m positive it was 30AMP for sure :(, I think 30AMP was Extreme overload no ?, googling stuff on breakers apparently there is “trip time”

Comment: If the wires in the wall, whether copper or aluminium, 'melt', you'd know, because your house would be burning down.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It would be the insulation melting or burning off, and even in that case it is quite rare for anything else to ignite. Possible, sure.

Comment: @jpa - The OP says 'did I melt wire'. Copper can melt in an overcurrent situation, as any electrical engineer will tell you. Of course, it is unlikely that an ordinary load would draw enough current, even if the company fuse or other protection allowed it. But the conductors could get hot enough to ignite wood, some plastics, and the vapours and gases from the overheated insulation would be toxic.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I guess we have just different interpretations :) I consider the insulation as part of the wire, and a melted wire to look like [this](https://www.thelocalelectrician.com.au/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/What-Are-The-Causes-Of-Melted-Wires.png). House not burning down is by no means a good indication of not having damaged cables.